# Installation of OTRS Windows Server 2003 and SQL DB

Tags: otrs

How can OTRS be installed on Windows Server 2003 alongside SQL Server? I already have SQL Server installed.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for this. I've edited it to the format we prefer for self-answered questions: the question contains the problem, and the answer contains the solution. Feel free to edit the question again if the 'initial problem' can be improved! +1

Comment: Also, see the comment under the answer from MichielB.

Comment: (Nominated for re-opening, as this is now in a S/O-compatible Q&A form)

Answer (score 1):

Posted on behalf of the OP:

1. download ActivePerl-5.16.3.1603-MSWin32
2. download otrs-3.1.15-win-installer-2.4.7
3. I create a folder under C:\ named "OTRS"
4. Install perl taking attention in the following:
   Custom Setup: I uncheck Documentation and examples since I dont want to to spend disk for that.
   Setup Options: I only select 3 first options
5. Install OTRS pointing to the OTRS directory. IMPORTANT: uncheck "continue web installer" before pressing "finish"
6. Install additional modules
   Open cmd and go to OTRS\otrs\bin, you should see a file named otrs.CheckModules.p
   execute: perl otrs.CheckModules.pl
   You will see modules missing, some are optional some required.
   for installing you can do: ppm install and the module to install, eg. "ppm install PDF::API2
   You can do also cpan PDF::API2
7. backup your file named "C:\OTRS\OTRS\Kernel\Config.pm"
8. Replace that file with the attached
9. May be necessary to edit home path, you can edit it with notepad.
10. Create DB in SQL server
    Open SQL Server Management Studio. Connect to your database server. Right-click on Databases and select New Database.
    Create a new database named OTRS
    Click on the DB to be sure you will affect with the scripts that DB.
    Select File > Open and select the file otrs\scripts\database\otrs-schema.mssql.sql
    Click "Execute". It may appear 3 warnings, dont worry.
    Select File > Open and select the file otrs\scripts\database\otrs-initial_insert.mssql.sql
    Click "Execute"
    Select File > Open and select the file otrs\scripts\database\otrs-schema-post.mssql.sql
    Click "Execute"
11. Creating login to access to the server, especifically to that DB.
    right-click Security and select New > Login
    type the login user. E.G. otrs
    Select SQL Server Authentication and Type "otrs" as password
    Uncheck box for Enforce password policy
    Set the OTRS database as the default database for the user.
    Still in that window, Select User Mapping on the left-hand side, select the OTRS database and the db_owner role.
    Click OK.
12. Testing connectivity.
    Go to cmd and to the directory c:\otrs\otrs\bin\
    run the command "perl otrs.CheckDB.pl" you should receive a message "It looks Ok!"
13. Now you can enter to your OTRS system, just double click on "OTRS Agent Interface" icon and type as user: root@localhots and pwd root.

Comment: You can achieve the same results - but easier -  with the new 3.0 Windows Installer: http://www.otrs.com/en/software/otrs-help-desk/features/otrs-windows-installer-30/ 

This allows you to use the web installer to set up your MS-SQL Server database.